# Windows 10 and the on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

In Windows 10 Professional, the available option is missing:

"Settings-> Devices-> Typing-> Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there is no keyboard attached to your device"

even though I am using the touch screen and no keyboard is connected. I need this option so that the on-screen keyboard appears automatically where I need to use it. Windows is up-to-date and I have a feeling this is a problem as this option is available on the second Win10Pro computer. Anyone have an idea how to turn it on?

**EDIT:**
The hardware is a Dell Optiplex computer with an Elo Solution touch monitor. The operating system is Windows 10 Professional 10.0.19042 Build 19042 ship with the computer. The device is not in tablet mode. I noticed that I am missing setting: devices -> typing -> touch keyboard settings.

I checked on a completely different POS machine (Windows 10 Home 10.0.19043 Build 19043) and the option and settings is available. I did a registry analysis to find the key corresponding to the setting change.

```
HKU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke = 1 (DWORD 32bit)
```

Unfortunately, manually adding a key to the registry doesn't trigger the option. I found a second place in the registry in the network where you can try to add a key - unfortunately it does not work.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\TipTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke = 1 (DWORD 32bit)
```

Below are the tablet settings in the system:

[image: Windows 10 Tablet Settings]

Comment: Tell us more about the device itself?  Is it a branded OEM device?  Did you install Windows yourself or did it come with Windows?  Verify the device is in Tablet mode.  What version of Windows 10 are you running exactly?  Post a screenshot of `System - Tablet` by performing an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic has been resolved. If no options are available:

"Settings-> Devices-> Typing-> Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there is no keyboard attached to your device"

Check if there is a "HID compatible touch screen" in the HID section of the device manager. In my case, despite the working touch, the device was missing. Choosing other drivers for the ELO monitor solved the problem.